# hox to redirect page with Ajax

Tags: ajax, redirect

I have this piece of code.

```
$('#river-selector').change(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (window.location.search.length) {
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
    }
    url += '?' + $(this).val();
    forward(url);
});
```

Instead of using the redirection (ie forward), I would use an ajax request but I do not know how?
Someone would have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I do not believe that this is something that you can do with AJAX, since AJAX is for making data (or other types of) requests from servers __without__ refreshing the page.

Comment: AJAX isn't for redirection.  It's for making asynchronous requests for external resources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect to a given URL? is that what you want?

Here is how to redirect in javascript to a given url

```
// HTTP redirect
window.location.replace(url);
```

or

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: Thx. Yes I would like to redirect to the url BUT without the page loads. I wish that you click on the dropdown list, the contents of the URL is displayed immediately without reloading the page. With ajax maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect a page with AJAX, but you can:

1. change a page with ajax via PAjax like techs;
2. change the url of current page with History API in modern browsers.

Comment: Thx. You could develop? I don't understand very well

Comment: @user2969259 You may search for tutorials for both solutions, and there are also many tools for both of that:

[jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax),

[history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)